# How to read nested json dumps

Tags: python, json

hey guys i am trying to read a json dump but don't know how to read the nested json dumps like lastTransactionID, or NAV.

I am also receiving the Attribute Error 'AccountDetails' object has no attribute 'get.

```
r = accounts.AccountDetails(accountID)
client.request(r)
print r.response
print r.get('lastTransactionID')
print r.get('NAV')
print r.get('unrealizedPL')

 {
    u'account': 
        {
        u'trades': [], 
        u'marginCloseoutNAV': u'99999.9998',
        u'marginUsed': u'0.0000', 
        u'marginCloseoutPositionValue': u'0.0000', 
        u'currency': u'EUR', 
        u'resettablePL': u'-0.0002', 
        u'NAV': u'99999.9998', 
        u'marginCloseoutMarginUsed': u'0.0000', 
        u'openTradeCount': 0, 
        u'marginCallMarginUsed': u'0.0000', 
        u'orders': [], 
        u'openPositionCount': 0, 
        u'positionValue': u'0.0000', 
        u'pl': u'-0.0002', 
        u'financing': u'0.0000', 
        u'pendingOrderCount': 0, 
        u'positions': 
            [
                    {
                    u'financing': u'0.0000',
                    u'short': 
                        {
                        u'units': u'0', 
                        u'financing': u'0', 
                        u'resettablePL': u'0.0000', 
                        u'unrealizedPL': u'0.0000', 
                        u'pl': u'0.0000'
                        }, 

                    u'commission': u'0.0000', 
                    u'unrealizedPL': u'0.0000', 

                    u'long': 
                        {
                        u'units': u'0', 
                        u'financing': u'0.0000', 
                        u'resettablePL': u'-0.0002', 
                        u'unrealizedPL': u'0.0000', 
                        u'pl': u'-0.0002'
                        }, 

                    u'instrument': u'AUD_USD', 
                    u'resettablePL': u'-0.0002', 
                    u'pl': u'-0.0002'
                    }
            ], 

        u'unrealizedPL': u'0.0000', 
        u'alias': u'Primary', 
        u'createdByUserID': xxx, 
        u'marginCloseoutUnrealizedPL': u'0.0000', 
        u'createdTime': u'2017-05-25T18:26:03.961466233Z', 
        u'balance': u'99999.9998'
        }, 

        u'lastTransactionID': u'255'
    }
```

Does someone know how to read the nested elements from the json dump?
Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Please format correctly your JSON payload. It's difficult to read as is.

Comment: And provide more context. What's the AccountDetails class ? What's a "client" object" (...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use json module for this:

```
import json

a = json.load(string_or_file_with_json)
# Now in a you have a dict, that represents json object
# You can write a simple recursive function, that will do something on every entry or smt like that
def do(json_dict):
   for k, v in json_dict.items():
       # !UPDATE, use isinstance(v, dict) instead of v is dict
       # Thx mister in comments
       if isinstance(v, dict): # if v is dict, than it's a nested json object
           do(x)
       else: # else it specific value
           your_action(k, v)
```

Comment: Use `isinstance(obj, type)` instead of `obj is type`.